# Mouse click event not working as expected

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, dom

I'm trying to search for a contact in Whatsapp Web search bar, first I want to focus in search bar and then enter the contact to execute the search.

I'm selecting the div with:

```js
const searchBox = document.querySelector("[data-testid=chat-list-search]") // returns div element

searchBox.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true })) // returns true
```

Dispatch event returns true but has no effect in search box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [`element.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) or [`element.select()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select), whichever better fits the goal (if you can target an [`<input>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) rather than a `div`, then the `focus` method might be a better choice because it will pre-select the input's text content).

If you only want to click the element, you can use [`element.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click).

> Note that, in any case, the app might be using event listener callbacks which choose not to respond to any event fired that doesn't have its [`event.isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) property set to `true` (and in this case, there's no way to programmatically interact with those targets by generating an event and dispatching it — or, in other words — without using native APIs in an environment like [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)).

Comment: Hi @jsejcksn, thanks for answering! focus and select didn't work as well, maybe it's expecting isTrusted for all listeners, is it possible to check wether its expecting isTrusted on listeners?

Comment: @NatanDeitch Sure — view the JS in the page using your browser's dev tools.

Comment: I couldn't confirm if the issue is with isTrusted indeed, now I'm using whatsapp-web.js that does the job. Thanks @jsejcksn!